# Getting a 403 from Bitbucket's REST API when trying to create an issue in a private issue tracker

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api, bitbucket-cloud

I have a Bitbucket Cloud App that has the issue:write, repository, pullrequest, and account scopes. According to their [docs](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-issue-tracker/#api-repositories-workspace-repo-slug-issues-post), all I should need is issue:write, and access to the repository (provided by the repository scope AFAIK). I can create issues on public issue trackers no problem, but if the repository's issue tracker is private I get a 403 status code and a message saying I need write or admin access.

I tried adding more scopes to my app, including repository:write and repository:admin, but nothing worked. So, I exchanged my JWT for an access token to check what scopes I actually had, and the new scopes didn't show up. I did verify that my token had issue:write, repository, pullrequest, and account scopes.

Is there some scope I'm missing or anything, and if so any ideas as to why I don't seem to get new scopes after updating my descriptor file/app and reinstalling it onto my workspace.